# Finding one sided limits algebraically

Tags: analysis, limits

I was wondering what the best method was for proving this limit algebraically:
$$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{3x^4-8x^3+5}{x^3-x^2-x+1}$$
I know the answer to this question is ;
$$\lim_{x \to 1^+}\frac{3x^4-8x^3+5}{x^3-x^2-x+1}={-\infty}$$ 
$$\lim_{x \to 1^-}\frac{3x^4-8x^3+5}{x^3-x^2-x+1}={+\infty}$$
The only way I can solve this is using the graph of the function as the limit becomes very apparent. What is the best way to answer this algebraically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the numerator and denominator is zero at $1$, let's factor out $(x-1)$ from both of them to get an idea how the function behaves around $1$.

The fraction equals $\dfrac{(3x^3-5x^2-5x-5)(x-1)}{(x^2-1)(x-1)}=\dfrac{3x^3-5x^2-5x-5}{x^2-1}$.

At $x=1$, the numerator equals $-12$. So for values around and very close to $1$, the numerator stays near $-12$.

The denominator however, is negative for $x<1$ and is positive for $x>1$. Thus, as $x$ approaches $1$ from the left, $x^2-1$ takes on values like $-0.1,-0.01,-0.001,\ldots$ while the numerator remains close to $-12$. Hence, the fraction is positive and becomes arbitrarily large as $x\to 1^{-}$.

Similarly, as $x\to 1^{+}$, the denominator is positive and becomes small while the numerator remains near $-12$ so that your expression here approaches $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

You've learned how to use features of polynomials and rational functions -- e.g. things like finding the zeroes and stuff -- to help you graph them, right?

You can use the same idea in reverse: what feature of a rational function corresponds to a pole? (i.e. to the graphical feature you've observed)

Comment: By using the graph, I meant that  simply plotted it, I do not think I have covered what a 'pole' is either . Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$3x^4-8x^3+5=(x-1)(3x^3-5x^2-5x-5)$$

$$x^3-x^2-x+1=(x-1)(x^2-1)=\ldots$$

Comment: $3x^4-8x^3+5=(x-1)(3x^3-5x^2\color{red}-5x\color{red}-5)$.

Comment: Taken care, @Alraxite. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
\frac{3x^4-8x^3+5}{x^3-x^2-x+1} = 3x - 5 + \frac{4}{x+1} - \frac{6}{x-1},
$$
which can be found by using [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) and [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition). From this form the limits $x\to 1^+$ and $x\to 1^-$ are easy to compute without looking at any plots.